# Synchronized multi-threading vs single thread

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore, synchronized

I am trying to count 100 numbers by multi-threading and single-threading. Since synchronized keyword allows only one thread at a time (it is kind of like a single thread), so these two methods below should have the same runtime approximately if we ignore the effect of time consuming of creating and synchronizing threads?

Multi-threading using synchronized:

```
public synchronized static void increment() {
    sum++;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                increment();
            }
        }
    });
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                increment();
            }
        }
    });
    t1.start();;
    t2.start();
    try {
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
```

Single-threading:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        sum++
    }

    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Comment: What is `t1` in the second approach? Do you mean `t3`?

Comment: yeah. I edited it. @AndyTurner

Comment: "Single-threading using synchronized:" Actually, that's multi-threaded. You've got the main thread and `t3`. And you're not using `synchronized`.

Comment: My bad. Please see my edit. @AndyTurner

Comment: What are you actually asking here?

Comment: My question is "synchronized multi-threading behaves similar with single threading and should have the approximate same run time"? @AndyTurner

Comment: That doesn't parse. If you are asking "do the two behave the same?" To which the answer is yes - the value of `sum` will be 100 at the end of both.

Comment: If we ignore the effect of time consuming in creating and synchronizing threads, their run time should be the same approximately? @AndyTurner

Comment: If you ignore the time taken to do all of the stuff which is different between the two, yes, they take the same time to run.

Comment: Regardless of programming language or the way you manage to coordinate that threads not interfere, you are spreading a sequential algorithm over multiple threads. It's guaranteed to never be faster (assuming perfect scheduling) than doing it in one.

Comment: For larger counts and the single threaded case the JIT could completly eliminate the loop and just print out the count. For the multi-threaded case this cannot be done, so the multi-threaded code will be much slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is really good at multithreading, but there is a lot of overhead with creating and synchronizing threads, so don't be surprised if, for a simple problem like counting to 100, you actually see an increase in runtime.

Comment: If we ignore the effect of time consuming of creating and synchronizing threads, their run time should be the same approximately? @Scott Twombly

Comment: Sure, but i think its unwise to do so. You can't separate the jvm from java. If you want to just count the number of times a number gets incremented, they are, of course, the same in both scenarios, but that's an almost meaningless metric. There are way more "things" happening and methods being called under the hood, in your multithreaded example, ignoring them makes me wonder, whats the point of comparing these things in the first place? @SHE

Comment: @SHE, you're missing Thomas Kläger's point (see his comment on your question, above).  A good compiler could recognize that the `sum` computed by your single-threaded example does not depend on any variable, on any function call, on any input whatsoever.  It's just a constant.  It's 4950, and it always will be 4950.  A good compiler could replace your entire loop with `sum = 4950;`, and that would not change the output of the program, but it would make it run a  whole lot faster.  But, no compilers could do that for the multi-threaded version.  Too complex.